# Error using HTTPURLConnection android when using emulator?

Tags: android, mysql

I keep getting an error:

```
02-03 12:03:14.728 12373-13627/com.example.XX.XXX W/System.err:     java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: J������
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXX W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.setStatusLine(RawHeaders.java:108)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXX. W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXX W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXX W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXX W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXX W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXXX W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXX W/System.err:     at com.example.XXXX.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:384)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXXX W/System.err:     at com.example.XXXX.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:325)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXXX W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXXX W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXX W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXXX W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXXX W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-03 12:12:48.638 18598-21942/com.example.XXXX W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The error occurs when getInputStream is called so I can only assume data isn't being written.
This is the code for my attempt at connecting. I am trying to insert data into MYSQL database on a local MAMP server. However I keep getting errors when connecting. I've tried replacing localhost:8889 with 10.0.2.2:8889 as told to online, as well as local ip, however this has not helped. The emulator is BlueStacks.

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            String jsonResponse = null;


        try{
            final String path = "http://10.0.2.2:8889/insert-db.php";
            //final String path = "http://192.168.0.11:8889/insert-db.php";
            URL finalURl = new URL(path);

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) finalURl.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8")
            );
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mEmail, "UTF-8") +
                    "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mPassword, "UTF-8");


            writer.write(data);
            Log.d("OUTPUT INFO STREAM", httpURLConnection.getOutputStream().toString());
            writer.flush();

            writer.close();
            os.close();

            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            Log.d("INPUTSTREAM", reader.readLine());
            is.close();


        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: From the error message it seems like you are violating the HTTP protocol - the status line of the received response is corrupted. Have you tried debugging your server? Can you see what is the exact response you are sending to your client?

Comment: Where is 10.0.2.2? This is emulator localhost address. This address not equal to your computer localhost because using NAT.

Comment: I can't connect directly to localhost from emulator so use 10.0.2.2, but get the same error when using localhost as parameter so this isnt the issue